# ActionListener not implemented

Tags: java, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I was learning about JRadiobuttons and I made three JRadioButtons in this particular program. The JRadioButtons were pizzaButton, burgerButton and hotdogButton. I wanted to print specific lines when one of them is selected by the user. I overrided the ActionPerformed method and even implemented the ActionListener for each one of the RadioButtons. But after every try, the program seemed to ignore the ActionPerformed method.
`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

``
`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JRadioButton pizzaButton;
    JRadioButton burgerButton;
    JRadioButton hotdogButton;

    MyFrame() {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JRadioButton pizzaButton = new JRadioButton("pizza");
        JRadioButton burgerButton = new JRadioButton("burger");
        JRadioButton hotdogButton = new JRadioButton("hot dog");

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(pizzaButton);
        group.add(burgerButton);
        group.add(hotdogButton);

        pizzaButton.addActionListener(this);
        burgerButton.addActionListener(this);
        hotdogButton.addActionListener(this);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(pizzaButton);
        this.add(burgerButton);
        this.add(hotdogButton);
        this.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==pizzaButton) {
            System.out.println("You ordered a pizza");
        } else if (e.getSource()==burgerButton) {
            System.out.println("You ordered a burger");
        } else if (e.getSource()==hotdogButton) {
            System.out.println("You ordered a hot dog");
        }
    }
}
```

``

I tried checking the things that could go wrong and double checked whether I added the the ActionListener to the JRadioButtons.

Answer (score 1):

In actionPerformed() you reference the buttons as class attributes, whereas in the constructor you use local variables, which mean different objects. Try to change:

```
        JRadioButton pizzaButton = new JRadioButton("pizza");
        JRadioButton burgerButton = new JRadioButton("burger");
        JRadioButton hotdogButton = new JRadioButton("hot dog");
```

into

```
        this.pizzaButton = new JRadioButton("pizza");
        this.burgerButton = new JRadioButton("burger");
        this.hotdogButton = new JRadioButton("hot dog");
```

Answer (score 1):

you overwrite your references, the actionPerformed compares 2 different objects.

Change

```
    JRadioButton pizzaButton = new JRadioButton("pizza");
    JRadioButton burgerButton = new JRadioButton("burger");
    JRadioButton hotdogButton = new JRadioButton("hot dog");
```

to

```
    pizzaButton = new JRadioButton("pizza");
    burgerButton = new JRadioButton("burger");
    hotdogButton = new JRadioButton("hot dog");
```